# Range of minutes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date-time, edit-form

I have a date field and time, and want to take this 5 minute interval in the select minutes, I want to be in sequence, example: 00,01,02,03,04,05,...55,56,57,58,59.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can add the following piece of code (on DOM ready) into the content editor webpart inside the new/edit form.

```
$("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").each(function() {
 var ddMinutes = $(this);
 ddMinutes.children().remove(); //Remove options 

 for(var i=0; i<60; i++) {
    if (i < 10){
         i = '0' + i;
    }
    $('<option />', {value: i, text: i}).appendTo(ddMinutes);
 }
});
```

Sharepoint's minute dropdown field has an id ending with DateTimeFieldDateMinutes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it worked this your idea, it only displays on the field but not saved in columns. 

I had another solution, not used selects SharePoint, made ​​by JQuery and changed by it and it worked.

Comment: @Renanfdo, could you please post your solution?

Comment: @grisha Create Dynamically 0 option field to 59 in a desirable list. After creating the item by css or javascript enter the select next to the date of the input (without the time options and minute), create a workflow created and changed. Within the workflow you add or set the time and the minute that the person selected in the field of time that you created.